LaTeX Workshop formatting issue: "LaTeX formatter is set to 'none'" after updating MiKTeX and LaTeXindent
I am using Visual Studio Code on Windows with MiKTeX and the LaTeX Workshop extension. I recently encountered an issue with automatic formatting not working and receiving the following message:
LaTeX formatter is set to "none" by formatting.latex.
Source: LaTeX Workshop


What I've Tried:

Updating MiKTeX:

I successfully updated all MiKTeX packages via the command line:
miktex packages update
miktex --admin packages update


I ran latexindent -v before the update and got this error:
Attempt to call undefined import method with arguments ("@logFileLines") via package "LatexIndent::Logger" (Perhaps you forgot to load the package?) at C:/Users/foobar/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/Document.pm line 30.
Attempt to call undefined import method with arguments ("$ifElseFiBasicRegExp") via package "LatexIndent::IfElseFi" (Perhaps you forgot to load the package?) at C:/Users/foobar/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/Special.pm line 25.
3.24.1, 2024-05-12


After updating, this error was resolved, and I now get the following:
3.24.4, 2024-07-18




LaTeX Workshop Configuration:

I added the following line to my .vscode/settings.json file:
"latex-workshop.latexindent.enabled": true


However, the automatic formatting still doesn't work, and I continue to see the "LaTeX formatter is set to 'none'" message.



My Setup:

OS: Windows
TeX Distribution: MiKTeX
Editor: Visual Studio Code with LaTeX Workshop extension
LaTeXindent version: 3.24.4 (after the update)

Question:
Why am I still getting the "LaTeX formatter is set to 'none'" message, and how can I enable automatic formatting in Visual Studio Code with LaTeX Workshop? Is there any additional configuration I need to set in LaTeX Workshop or MiKTeX?

I managed to resolve the issue by explicitly adding the following line to my local .vscode/settings.json file:
"latex-workshop.formatting.latex": "latexindent"

After doing this, the automatic formatting started working again.
What’s strange is that it worked without this line in the past, but adding it manually fixed the issue this time. It seems like the LaTeX Workshop extension may have changed or reset some settings during updates.
So, if you're facing the same issue, try adding this configuration to ensure latexindent is properly set as the formatter.

Same thing, however, more visual. In the LatexWorkshop settings, modify:

